# How to assign value to "text" property of "someText" object in kinetic js?

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

Here is the code below: Actually I am using a loop in which i want to assign value to  "text" property

```
var someText=new Kinetic.Text({
    x:stage.width()-50,
    y:stage.height()/4,
    text:9, //i want to change value of this property
    fill:'green',
    fontSize:14,
    fontFamily:'Verdana'
});

someText.text()=19;  // here is the error fires
```

`"invalid assignment left-hand side"` error fires in the above statement. pls help? If i execute `alert(someText.text())` its works fine and `9` is displayed

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
someText.text("19");
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you try to set your text is not valid. Try:

```
someText.setText('19');
```